# Variable Error with macro in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

I am new to VBA in excel and I ran into an error that I am unsure how to interpret. I was wondering if somebody could help. I am trying to create s table of contents for an excel file and I found a macro online. It is posted below:

```
Sub Create_TOC()
Dim wbBook As Workbook
Dim wsActive As Worksheet
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim lnRow As Long
Dim lnPages As Long
Dim lnCount As Long
Set wbBook = ActiveWorkbook
With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With
    'If the TOC sheet already exist delete it and add a new
    'worksheet.
On Error Resume Next
With wbBook
    .Worksheets(“TOC”).Delete
    .Worksheets.Add Before:=.Worksheets(1)
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Set wsActive = wbBook.ActiveSheet
With wsActive
    .Name = “TOC”
    With .Range(“A1:B1”)
        .Value = VBA.Array(“Table of Contents”, “Sheet # – # of Pages”)
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
End With
lnRow = 2
lnCount = 1
‘Iterate through the worksheets in the workbook and create
‘sheetnames, add hyperlink and count & write the running number
‘of pages to be printed for each sheet on the TOC sheet.
For Each wsSheet In wbBook.Worksheets
    If wsSheet.Name <> wsActive.Name Then
        wsSheet.Activate
        With wsActive
            .Hyperlinks.Add .Cells(lnRow, 1), “”, _
            SubAddress:=”‘” & wsSheet.Name & “‘!A1”, _
            TextToDisplay:=wsSheet.Name
             lnPages = wsSheet.PageSetup.Pages().Count
            .Cells(lnRow, 2).Value = “‘” & lnCount & “ - ” & lnPages
        End With
        lnRow = lnRow + 1
        lnCount = lnCount + 1
    End If
Next wsSheet
wsActive.Activate
wsActive.Columns(“A:B”).EntireColumn.AutoFit
With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

The error which I received was this:

```
Compile Error: Variable TOS not defined.
```

I am really new to this and I am unsure about what this means. Could somebody provide a detailed explanation on what the problem is and how to go about fixing it.

Comment: Have you included "Option Explicit" at the top of your code? This forces you to define all your variables. This might help find the problem!

Comment: That is actually included in the file already it is highlight the TOS

Comment: Where is TOS in your code?

Comment: Sorry the error message just says Compile error: Variable not defined"

Comment: If it says that it would highlight the variable in question. did it?

Comment: Look at all those curlies...

Comment: Yes, it was "TOC". I think part of the problem I'm having now is due to copying and pasting the code in, since re-typing the text gets rid of some of the errors. I'm now having trouble with the two lines that start with SubAddress and TextToDisplay- it says 'Compile error: Method or data member not found'.

Comment: replace all `“` and  `”` with  `"`

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is in the quotation marks, there are angled/curly brackets being used and this is stopping the code being read properly.

Taking the first instance of the issue: -

```
.Worksheets(“TOC”).Delete
```

You receive the error:-

> Compile Error:
>
> Variable not defined

and `“TOC”` is highlighted. This is occurring because the wrong quotation marks are being so `TOC` is not being seen as a literal string but instead `“TOC”` is being presumed to be a variable, that is not defined (i.e. does not exist).

This can be fixed by going through your code and replacing all the below: -

Change `“` (Angled open quotation) to `"` (straight quotation (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>)

Change `”` (Angled close quotation) to `"` (straight quotation (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>)

Change `‘` (Angled apostrophe) to `'` (straight single quotation (<kbd>'</kbd>, shares the <kbd>@</kbd> key)

Comment: Note that the "Shift+2" and "shares the @ key" parts are entirely dependent on your keyboard layout and locale. Shift+2 makes a "@" on my en-US keyboard, and I get a single quote using the '/" key. That part of your answer is probably better off left out.

Comment: Got it- changing the quotation marks fixed a lot of it, but I'm still running into problems with SubAddress and TextToDisplay. Any idea how to solve those issues?